# Data for calculating Vellocity Chart in Rally

Tags: rest, rally

I was working on a project to pull out data from rally and create a vellocity chart.

I understand the REST Web Service APIs to use are Defects, Iteration,Hierarchical requirement and Iterationcumilativeflow data.

But can you please tell me how the actual calcualtions are done to calculate the velocity per iteration for a particular project.

What all data are required and how it can be achieved. Right now im able to pull planestimate of all accepted user stories and total plan estimate.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be a duplicate of [Velocity Chart in Rally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104696/vellocity-chart-in-rally).

In that post I answered: "I wrote an app recently to calculate velocity. I used the story points of all accepted stories/defects in a time period (iteration/release). My numbers ended up matching what Rally had for my velocity, so I believe that is all it takes."